# Получить значения параметров JSON файла

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, postman

Делаю веб-сервис, для его работы необходимо получить значения параметров, в данном случае - ("article", "id", "color", "size") . Для тестирования использую Postman с запросом POST и в тело цикла ввожу json-код

```
{"test": "test1"
  "plan": {
    "items": [
      {
        "item": {
          "items": [
            {
              "modificator": "article"
            },
            {
              "modificator": "id"
            },
            {
            "modificator": "color"
            },
            {
            "modificator": "size"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

При этом в контроллере пишу такой код

```
public class Item3
        {
            public string modificator { get; set; }
        }

        public class Item2
        {
            public List<Item3> items { get; set; }
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public Item2 item { get; set; }
        }

        public class Plan
        {
            public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Plan plan { get; set; }
        }

        [Route("~/api/ApiProd")]
        [HttpPost]
        public string Show([FromBody] Item3 item3)
        {
            return item3.modificator;
        }
```

Когда отправляю запрос в Postman, то могу получить только значение "test1", подскажите, как правильно получить доступ ко всем параметрам

Comment: Если вы составляли этот JSON, то он ужасен. По вопросу - у вас невалидный JSON, как минимум не хватает запятой после `"test": "test1"`. Также я не вижу структуре классов это `test` свойство, как же вы тогда его достали?

Comment:  нет, json составляла не я, в этом и проблема, его должен отправить посторонний ресурс, я просто пытаюсь получить из него данные сейчас в тестовом режиме. Да, я сейчас удалила это test свойство, чтоб никого не запутать, оно не нужно, просто хотелось сказать, что  это свойство я получить могу, а вот как достать остальные, пока не разобралась 

Comment: можешь получать объект на входе, а потом этот объект переводить уже в entity dto (не красиво конечно, но очень просто), либо objectToJson

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас нет запятой после "test": "test1"
2. Вы не добавили тест в корневой объект:

---

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    public Plan plan { get; set; }
}
```

---

3. Show должен принимать не Item3, а RootObject, в котором вы потом будете обращаться к нужным вам данным:

---

```
 [Route("~/api/ApiProd")]
 [HttpPost]
 public string Show([FromBody] RootObject model)
 {
      return model.plan.items[0].item.items[0].modificator;
 }
```